# Состояние представления элементов

Tags: asp.net, c#

Я новичок в ASP.NET и не очень разбираюсь в тонкостях этой платформы. Хочется использовать весь функционал платформы, но иногда сталкиваюсь с проблемами из-за которых приходится отказываться от многих вещей. 
Суть проблемы.

На странице есть серверный элемент DropDownList (пусть с ID=CategoryDropDownList).
В Page_Load я его заполняю и считываю значение:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   Заполняю значениями
}
// считываю значение
string categoryText = CategoryDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Вроде все хорошо работает, но при добавлении ссылки для сортировки данных

```
<a href="?sort=desc">Сортировка</a>
```

Все значения выпадающего списка теряются (так как ссылка не отправляет страницу обратно серверу, а запрашивает ее снова). Как исправить данную проблему?

**Обновление**

Можно, конечно, при заполнении элемента CategoryDropDownList проверять параметр Request.QueryString["category"] и выбирать нужную категорию. НО. Тогда теряется весь смысл с состоянием представления элемента CategoryDropDownList. Хочется найти решение как сделать ссылку для сортировки, чтобы выбор элемента CategoryDropDownList не терялся.

Comment: DropDownList - работает по post ответу, а при использовании <a href="?sort=desc">Сортировка</a>, отправляется GET на уже, как бы, новую страницу (все значения состояния представления теряются).
Я решил проблему использованием LinkButton.